# Creating database independent rules within a C# application - rules engine?

Tags: c#, sql, rules, rule-engine

I am writing an application using NHibernate and one of the requirements is to create rules for the system that will effectively generate SQL queries to filter data. These rules are application user maintainable.

As an example you might have a rule for releasing orders that is called

**ForeignOrders**  which would be set up something like *Order* **(Business Object)** *DeliveryCountry* **(Business Object Property)** <> **UK**

or

**ExpensiveLondonAcmeOrders** which would be set up something like *Order* **(Business Object)** *DeliveryCity* **(Business Object Property)** = **London** *AND* Order *TotalAmount (Business Object Property)*  > **1000** AND Order *CompanyName* = **ACME**

Then when the user comes to release orders they chose which rule template they want to use and will only release orders that meet those criteria.

The names of the Business Objects and Business Object Properties closely reflect the underlying data / domain model but how would you be able to determine and display these in the user interface at run time and then create in essence the where clause for an SQL query. Also, once defined you will also need to store the values in a database with database platform independence.

Ideally, I do not want to write this functionality - could you achieve something like this using a rules engine? If so, which and expensive ones are not really an option. If not, what resources are available to get to grips with how to write this.

Thanks for any help it will be really useful

Comment: Just remember that people unused to how boolean logic _actually_ works will usually be confused about how `AND` and `OR` conditions work in SQL, given how they are usually used in the english language.

Comment: Ah, the power of buzz words... rules engines don't do what you want them to do - they are basically machines that sit in workflows and apply business rules.

Comment: I thought that my understanding of rules engines might be incorrect as it is not something I've ever spent a lot of time with. I just need to know the correct terminology for what I'm describing.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth reading "Domain driven design" by Eric Evans - it deals with a lot of the stuff you're asking for. Specifically, Evans proposes the Specification Pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) - a way of applying boolean logic to objects without knowing in advance what the criteria are.

http://www.dimecasts.net/Content/WatchEpisode/139 has a walkthrough that may also help...

Comment: I'm new here so I am not sure if it is the correct etiquette to write this here. If so, apologies. I have considered using the Specification pattern and returning a DetachedCriteria which is fine if you know the properties you need to include at Build time. However, in this case we do not. The properties to include in the specification are only known at run time.How would one go about implementing the specification pattern in this scenario?

Comment: Can you fix your broken link @Neville K?

Answer (score 0):

Rules engines won't help much... they just apply rules within a workflow...

Checkout [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) - another option is [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) .